# C - fopen sometimes works, and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: c, null, cmd, fopen

I'm using "Visual Studio 2010" on "Windows 7 32bit", and I'm working on my "debug" build.

In my program I use fopen to access a file using this code:

```
FILE *f = fopen("simple_test.asm", "r");
```

When I run (F5) it returns a NULL pointer.
When I use full path it works well.

The strange thing is, when I open the file through cmd, it works like a charm even when I don't use full path!

Can someone please shed some light on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the working directory. In the `cmd` shell, you might be in a different directory than visual studio uses to run your program. You should be able to set the working directory in the Project Settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcw4dzyf.aspx

Comment: The debugger might start it up with a different current directory. Does it work if you pass a fully-qualified path to `fopen`?

Comment: @ruakh I dislike guessing (too much) in answers, I'll just repost if the guess turns out to be right.

Comment: It was a problem with current directory - VS2010 sets it differently then I expected.
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory for Visual Studio 2010 might not be the directory that has simple_test.asm.

As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks that worked!
Apparently working directory is set to be the one with *.vcxproj
and the source files, and not the one with debug files

Answer (score 1):

fopen takes a second argument specifing the mode, "r" for read "r+" for reading and writing and so on.

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```